# Reflection Method Invoke - Failed to convert parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a static method that has the signature:

```
pubic static foo (float, float, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>)
```

I'm using reflection to call this method with arguments of

```
int, int, and List<List<double>>,
```

This fails, it appears to me that the `List<List<double>>` parameter is failing to be converted. I'm using the code below to attempt to convert parameters.

Is this possible? A limitation of reflection? I would have thought that `List<double>` implemented the `IEnumerable` interface and would just work.

```
var args = inputportvals.Select(x=>
                             {
            if (x.First is IronPython.Runtime.List || x.First is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider)
            {
                return x.First;
            }

            if (x.First is IEnumerable || x.First is IList)
            {
                return x.First as IEnumerable;
            }
            else
            {
                return Convert.ChangeType(x.First, infos.Where(y=>y.Name == x.Second).First().ParameterType);
            }
        }
        ).ToArray();
 
funcdef.MethodPointer.Invoke(null, args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<List<double>>` is not convertible to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>`:

```
List<List<double>> x = null;
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> y = x; //does not compile and fails with an explicit cast
```

You need to perform the conversion yourself. For example:

```
x.Cast<IEnumerable<double>>()
```

Comment: Thank You, can you explain to me why that is so when List<double> is convertible to IEnumerable<double>?